# What is the gas cost to read a member of a global struct?

Tags: solidity, storage, struct, memory

Say I have a global state variable `struct` `MyStruct` that has multiple members/attributes/fields, what is the gas cost for reading a specific member? Is it equivalent to the gas cost of reading the entire struct or much less and proportionate to that member. So if a struct has 16 `uint` members, then is the gas cost for reading/loading just 1 of the 16 members from storage approximately 1/16 the gas cost of reading/**SLOAD**ing the entire struct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The costs of reading a full struct from storage in a contract heavily depends on your struct.

You pay gas costs for every storage slot that you access. If your struct spans multiple storage slots and you read them all at once (by loading the whole struct) you will pay more gas than only loading a specific member of the struct.

But Solidity can fit multiple parameters into one slot. (see [related question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/122267/solidity-uint-syntax-definition-the-documentation/122274#122274) and [Solidity docs](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.12/internals/layout_in_storage.html#layout-of-state-variables-in-storage)). In this case reading all at once is cheaper since you only access one storage slot one time.

These struct storage optimizations of Solidity become more important when you update a struct (so storage writes) as writing multiple storage slots is significantly more expensive than writing a single storage slot.

Note: Repeatedly writing or reading the same storage slots became a lot cheaper with [EIP-2929](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-2929)

Answer (score -3):

Reading data from Blockchain does not cost any gas.

Comment: It can if you submit a valid transaction to the network, even if you're not modifying state, you have services like Etherscan who run their own archive nodes which allow you to read contract state for free, but technically it's still possible to execute a view call directly on chain, so my question is in this context.

Comment: @MShakeG the op says nothing about sending transactions

Comment: I think it's implied since it's a given that gas is only charged if a transaction is executed on the network.

Comment: Well, the OP should ask that then. If the question is posed what "the gas cost to read" anything from a blockchain is ... the asnwer is simple "nothing". I'm not gonna asssume that OP is talking about txs unless he states that in his question ... otherwise, he might as well be talking about unicorns; so yeah, this is pretty much the first time I get downvoted for answering a question correctly ...