# Solidity uint syntax definition the documentation

Tags: solidity, solidity-0.8.x

Just curious of the following [example](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.12/internals/layout_in_memory.html?highlight=uint#example-for-difference-in-struct-layout) from the documentation.
How to related the digit 8 in `uint8` and 32 bytes? Thanks in advance.

*The following array occupies 32 bytes (1 slot) in storage, but 128 bytes (4 items with 32 bytes each) in memory.*

`uint8[4] a;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number of the `uintX` type is in `bits` (as this is common for number representation in many languages). Therefore a `uint` that uses the full width  (32 bytes) available in Solidity would be a `uint256`.

In general you have the following conversion:
`1 slot = 1 word = 32 bytes = 256 bits`

Regarding the `storage` and `memory` related part:
In memory Solidity always pads all values to 32 bytes, therefore an `uint8` will use the same memory as a `uint256`, but in storage Solidity optimized the usage, to avoid additional gas costs, therefore it only uses the minimal storage required. In case of a `uint8` this would be 1 bytes. Therefore you can store up to 32 `uint8` in one storage slot (see conversions above)